# Parse Windows Command Line Output To Get PIDs

Tags: command-line, window, command, pid, netstat

I'm looking to gather only the PID value outputted when you run this netstat command:

```
netstat -a -o -n -p tcp | findstr -i "CLOSE_WAIT"
```

My intention is to use the PIDs and create a script that will run `taskkill /PID pidfoundhere` to remove any sockets with CLOSE_WAIT state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
    for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('
        netstat -noa -p tcp ^| find /i "CLOSE_WAIT"
    ') do if not "%%a"=="0" echo taskkill /pid %%a
```

Use `for` command to split the line using the spaces as delimiters, get the 5th token in the line and if there is PID, kill the process

The `taskkill` commands are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command

Comment: I modified it a little bit to be a little more specific but I have another question. Any clue how to execute this command in Java? I'm having some issues running it as: 

String command = "@echo off for /f \"tokens=5\" %%a in ('netstat -noa -p tcp ^| find /i \"CLOSE_WAIT\" ^| find /i \""+ip+":443\" ') do if not \"%%a\"==\"0\" echo taskkill /pid %%a";
Process runCommand = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

Currently getting an error: Cannot run program "@echo": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Also tried it as passing a String[] to the exec() method and getting a cannot run program error.

Comment: @user3459799, sorry, java is not my area, but the code, as is, is intended to be executed inside a batch file. If you want to run it from java, and not use a batch file, you will need to use `cmd /c "the command"` as `cmd` is who knows how to execute it, remove the `@echo off`, place all the command in one line and replace all the `%%a` (the percent is escaped inside batch files) with `%a` for command line version.